# ASP.NET,C# :How to handle Shopping cart Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce

I am developing an e-commerce project, in this I have one crucial product that have only one ProductQuantity,and that product have quantity 1 so two person can not buy that product.
at the time of AddToCart I have reduced the quantity from the database.
I have test this with 10 machine and at the same time all 10  machine click on the AddToCart Button,but 3 machine is able to add the same product to own cart, which is wrong, only one machine(person) can add that product.

Please suggest me how to handle this scenario.

Thanks
Vijendra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add to cart, you shouldn't really be removing one from the ProductQuantity, it should stay as is. Only when the order has been paid for do you drop it from the quantity.

Otherwise you end up with the scenario of someone coming to the site, adding a bunch of stuff to the cart, then leaving and never coming back, now all your products are 1 less in stock even tho your inventory would be 1 greater than ProductQuantity.

The products can display something like 'low in stock' or 'less than 5 available'. The end user knows there isn't many left, then when you get to the checkout, you can confirm the quantity to ensure it hasn't been sold prior while the user was fluffing around. If the product is now out of stock, then display a message saying it's no longer in stock.

The flipside of the coin here is, it's going to be rare for you to have a scenario where this actually occurs, unless your site is really popular.

---

**Edit: *Additional answer to address 'I want 10 people' comment***

If you say you want 10 people to try add it, with only 1 person to successfully add it, then you are doing yourself out of business.

If User A add's the product to the cart, User B cannot.

User B leaves the site looking for where he can buy the product.

User A then leaves cos he decided he no longer wants the product, the product is now back in the database, and you have lost a potential sale.

Comment: @Phill: if some one come add the product to the cart and leave the cart without purchasing , for that I have add the product back to Database on the Session_End event.

Comment: @Phill: I want like 10 different people try to add the same product(which have quantity 1)at the same time, in this case what should I do that only one person can able to add that product.

Comment: In my scenario it allows all 10 people to add the same product. You cannot rely on 'Session_End' to add the product back in the database, since the session end event is only raised for InProc sessions, when using StateServer or SQLServer for session management there is no session end.

Comment: @Phill: This ste is really very popular,during rally at the same there are arround 30000 people try to buy the limited 1000 product have only quantity 1 because these are RV Spaces.
So this is very important no two people can buy the same Product.

Comment: Ok so you have 30k people which means you have more than 1 web server, which means you're not using InProc sessions which means you cannot rely on Session_End. Again my scenario does not allow two people to buy the same product, it allows both users to add the product to their cart, it verifies just before the transaction is completed that the product is still infact available. IF the product is not available then it wouldn't take the transaction.

Comment: Yes I agree with Phill, the way in which he is handling product to be added in cart.

Answer (score 0):

After the first time that "Add To Cart" is clicked, have you checked the database to verify that the count has indeed reduced to 0?

Secondly, once the count is at 0, have you verified that additional clicks to "Add to Cart" check the quantity field to make sure that there is sufficient quantity to fill their order?

I suspect that the problem is with one or the other of these two areas...

Comment: I want like 10 different people try to add the same product(which have quantity 1)at the same time, in this case what should I do that only one person can able to add that product.